# Performance of concurrency in Django (apache2 prefork/mod_wsgi), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: django, performance, concurrency, apache2, mod-wsgi

First of all I am not in any way unhappy with the performance of my Django powered site, its not getting massive traffic, a bit over 1000 visits per day so far.

I was curious how well it would cope with heavy traffic peaks so I used the ab-tool to do some benchmarking.

I noticed that the performance when the concurrency is larger than 1 delivers the same ammount of request as 1 concurrent connection.

**Shouldn't the reqs/s increase with concurrency?**

Im on a virtual machine with 1 GB of RAM, apache2 (prefork), mod_wsgi, memcached and mysql.
All content on the page has been cached, database does not take any hits. And if memcached would drop the entry, theres only 2 light (indexed) queries - and should immediately be re-cached.

**Benchmarking data:** (note: i did benchmark it with 2000 and 10k requests with the same results)

For the startpage, served through apache2/mod_wsgi by django:
-n100 -c4: http://dpaste.com/97999/ (58.2 reqs/s)
-n100 -c1: http://dpaste.com/97998/ (57.7 reqs/s)

For robots.txt, directly from apache2:
-n100 -c4: http://dpaste.com/97992/ (4917 reqs/s)
-n100 -c1: http://dpaste.com/97991/ (1412 reqs/s)

This is my apache conf: http://dpaste.com/97995/

**Edit: Added more information**

wsgi.conf: http://dpaste.com/98461/

mysite.conf: http://dpaste.com/98462/

**My wsgi-handler:**

```
import os, sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: You don't indicate whether Apache is compiled with prefork or worker MPM. You don't supply the configuration you are using to have your application hosted by mod_wsgi, so no idea if you are using embedded mode or daemon mode. Using 100 requests for a benchmarking sample will also not generate good results, normally you would want to use thousands. Also can't tell if you have made sure you have eliminated startup delays. Apache/mod_wsgi will lazily load the Python web application. Also no indication if your request is against a database and whether it's the problem. More information needed.

Comment: Added more information. I did benchmark it with 2000 and 10k requests with the same results.
The request does not hit the database at all, I've made sure everything is cached (memcached), and top tells me its only the apache processes that are using (up all) resources.

Comment: Oh and i actually had "prefork" in the header, so that info was provided. Added it to the text now for clarity.

Comment: so glad you've used dpaste ... dead links everywhere :) Very helpful for the community indeed!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are using prefork MPM and mod_wsgi in embedded mode with lots of processes, you are possibly killing the performance of your box. For a start, suggest you read:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/03/load-spikes-and-excessive-memory-usage.html

Using embedded mode like you are, you need to tune your MPM parameters carefully. Setting MaxRequestsPerChild to be non zero is not a good start as you are going to periodically force out the Apache processes, with the result that you will cause a load spike as everything has to reload.

Would suggest worker MPM and with your Python web application running in mod_wsgi daemon mode. This for a start will result in a lot less processes being run, less memory overhead, and give more predictability around the performance of the system. Can then start to look more closely at why things may be running slower.

One thing to pay attention to is what you get for the following section of 'ab' output:

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       0
Processing:     0    0   0.2      0       2
Waiting:        0    0   0.1      0       2
Total:          0    0   0.2      0       2
```

If the max column shows large values, then you are getting hit by the application loading costs due to your either not eliminating them from your tests through preloading, or by short process restart interval.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise mod_wsgi could run in daemon mode. I'm gonna read this through a couple of times and tweak my settings.

If i read your suggestion correctly, you're saying I should not run the prefork version of apache2?

Comment: If you are using daemon mode to run Python WSGI application, not so critical that you be running worker MPM as Python code no longer running in core Apache server child processes. If you are also running PHP using mod_php, you will still be stuck with running prefork MPM anyway. Still, if not dependent on mod_php or any other Apache modules which require single threaded Apache processes, then better off using worker MPM. Even if you do still have to run single threaded prefork MPM, the mod_wsgi daemon processes can still be multithreaded.